# How to have multiple template images for video in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am creating a program that records the screen of a game and does template matching to react to set actions. I am wondering how it would be best to return the path name of each template image when it is highlighted by OpenCV as the current solution loops through the array causing issues such as the reaction happening multiple times?

I tried putting the images in an array and iterating through causing issues with the program as stated.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time
import glob
import pyautogui

def ow_check(image):
    original_image = image
    # convert to gray
    processed_img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # template
    template_data = []
    files1= glob.glob('F:\Coding\Python\Test\Templates\*.png')
    for myfile in files1:

        template = cv2.imread(myfile,0)
        template_data.append(template)

    for tmp in template_data:
        (w, h) = tmp.shape[::--1]
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(processed_img, tmp, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        threshold = 0.8
        loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
        #drawing of the rectangle
        for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
            cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 2)
            #print('target spotted')
            for file in files1:
                template2 = cv2.imread(file,0)
                if np.array_equal(template2,tmp):
                    print(file)
                    if file == 'F:\Coding\Python\Test\Templates\BS.PNG':
                        # gives us time to get situated in the game
                        #overworld code
                        print('s')
                        pyautogui.keyDown('s') 
                        pyautogui.keyUp('s')
                        time.sleep(1.0)
```

to just return the if file portion only once instead of several times?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Sort the retrieved filenames, so you can connect actions to specific array positions.

```
files1 = sorted(glob.glob('F:\Coding\Python\Test\Templates\*.png'))
```

Then use enumerate to loop through the templates. This returns the template and it's index.

```
for index, tmp in enumerate(template_data):
```

If a match is found, you can use the index to determine the action to be taken.

For example, if 'BS.png' is the first image-file alphabetically, perform the required actions when index is 0.